# Приведение базы к 3-ей нормальной форме

Tags: база-данных

У меня есть 5 таблиц:

- 1-ая: ID товара;товар
- 2-ая: ID города;город
- 3-ая: ID поставщика;поставщик
- 4-ая: ID фирмы;фирма
- 5-ая: ID поставки;ID товара;ID фирмы;ID города;ID
  поставщика;количество

ON DELETE/UPDATE не использую, т.к. 5-ая. таблица должна оставаться неизменной,даже если произошли изменения в других таблицах

- Значение tovarname берётся из колонки idtov таблицы tovar.
- Значение postname берётся из колонки idpost таблицы providers.
- Значение gorodname берётся из колонки idgor таблицы gorod.
- Значение firmname берётся из колонки idfirm таблицы firms.

Они соответствуют 1-ой нормальной форме, т.к. все строки различны,и не являются списками.
Т.к соответствует 1-ой нормальной форме и имеет уникальный id, то значит и второй нормальной форме соответствует.
Правильно рассуждаю?
Вот с 3-ей формой немного непонятно. "Любой её не ключевой атрибут функционально зависит только от первичного ключа."

Что значит функционально?
[image: изображение]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предположим у вас была бы еще таблица стран. И в таблицу поставок вы бы помимо `ID` города внесли `ID` страны, причем это была бы именно страна этого города. Т.е. у вас во всех записях с `ID -> "Москва"` стояла бы страна `ID -> "РФ"`. В таком случае можно было бы говорить, что поле `Страна` функционально зависит от поля `Город`. При смене города пришлось бы менять и страну.

3 НФ как раз говорит о том, что такого быть не должно. Страна должна быть указана в таблице городов, а в поставках быть только `ID` города.

Comment: Спасибо большое за разъяснение про функциональную зависимость
Т.е моя база приведена к 3-ей нормальной форме?

Comment: @ExzoTikFruiT Что означает город в таблице поставок ? Что поставка идет в этот город ? или он как то связан с фирмой или провайдером.

Comment: Да,что поставка идёт в этот город.
Т.е фирма имеет филиалы в разных городах

Comment: @ExzoTikFruiT я думал фирма - это производитель. А это покупатель что ли ? предлагаю более понятно называть сущности.  хотя с НФ это конечно не связано. В общем да, у вас база в 3 НФ. Единственное, что немного напрягает ... у вас одно и то же юридическое лицо не может случайно в одних поставках выступать как "фирма", а в других как "поставщик" ?

Comment: Да,надо переименовать. Поставщика будет правильнее переименовать в Производителя.
А как правильно сформулировать доказательство 3-ей нормальной формы? Я пишу курсовую,и надо всё по полочкам разложить. Мои формулировки первой и второй форм подойдут?

Comment: @ExzoTikFruiT  доказательство ... может прямо исходя из определения 3 НФ: ни один не ключевой атрибут в таблицах не зависит ни от каких либо других атрибутов кроме первичного ключа. (ну и то что находиться при этом в 2НФ). И еще не упоминайте лучше "филиалы". просто, такая то фирма ждет поставку в таком то городе. А почему - это ее личное дело. А то я бы придрался а не стоит ли филиалы занести в базу, раз города как то от них зависят :)

Comment: Спасибо огромное